# why the results of this code are same?

Tags: c#

```
static void increment(int num)
{
    num++;
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{   
    int x = 30;
    Console.WriteLine(x);
    increment(x);
    Console.WriteLine(x);
}
```

Hi, I am wondering why the result of this code is **30** and **30**, NO ANY CHANGE? thanks!

Comment: please consult a basic tutorial

Comment: try initializing outside the method

Comment: Although I lost a lot of reputation, still happy to get the answer!

Comment: @Freelancer: Not only is w3schools a decidedly bad website, it has nothing to do with C#.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because in function increment, parameter is passed by value, not by reference.

If you want to see x changed, either do

```
static int increment (int num)//parameter passed by value, but function now returns an incremented value, not void.
    {
        num++;
        return num;
    }
        static void Main (string[] args)
    {   
        int x=30;

        Console.WriteLine(x);
        x = increment(x);
        Console.WriteLine(x);
    }
```

or

```
static void increment (ref int num)//num is passed by ref now
    {
        num++;
    }
        static void Main (string[] args)
    {   
        int x=30;

        Console.WriteLine(x);
        increment(ref x);
        Console.WriteLine(x);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

the reason is because the value of int is being passed, not the reference.

If you changed increment to accept (ref int) and called it - `increment (ref x)` it would change it

Comment: thanks! although I lost a lot of reputation, still happy to get the answer!

Comment: hopefully your nice thanks will get you some back :)

Answer (score 0):

Because `int` is a [value type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/34yytbws%28v=vs.71%29.aspx). It is not passed by reference. It is passed by value (copy created and passed into method). So, any modifications to `num` parameter in `increment` method do not affect value of `x` in calling code. Only copy of `x` value is modified in `increment` method.

```
static void increment(int num) // here you have copy of x
{
    num++; // copy is modified
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{   
    int x = 30;
    Console.WriteLine(x);
    increment(x); // x stays here and not passed into method
    Console.WriteLine(x);
}
```

Comment: thanks! although I lost a lot of reputation, still happy to get the answer!

Comment: @user2049259 one downvote is not a lot of reputation :)

Answer (score 0):

Your increment method essentially does absolutely nothing. It doesn't return a modified value. The `num++` line will increment `num` by one, but then you don't return anything from it. So `num` will always be the same. You could pass by ref using the `ref` keyword for example

```
static void increment (ref int num)
{
    num++;
}
```

Which would change the value of num giving you `31` on your second writeline call.

Comment: thanks! although I lost a lot of reputation, still happy to get the answer!

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that you have passed num variable by value not by reference. When passing by value, the value of the variable is copied into the local copy, then local copy is incremented but destroyed later after the method finishes. If you pass your variable by reference, then the address of the variable is passed to the method and the original variable is changed, not its copy.

```
static void increment (ref int num)
    {
        num++;
    }
```

And then you call this method with

```
increment(ref x);
```

The `int` is value type and like all other value types is always passed by value if keyword `ref` isn't used. Unlike these, class types are passed as references and changing them in methods changes the original object.

Answer (score 0):

x is locally defined.

If you try to print `Console.WriteLine(num);` in `increment (int num)`

It will print 31.

Answer (score 0):

int is a value type, you need to declare your parameter as ref:

```
static void increment (ref int num)
```